# Retrofit Form Submission

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I am attempting to login to a CAS service by filling out a login form using RetroFit. This is my authentication interface:

```
public interface AuthService {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/cas/login")
    void login(@Field("username") String username,
            @Field("password") String password, Callback<Response> result);
}
```

When I attempt to use this interface, and print the results:

```
new RestClient().getAuthService().login(
        mUsername.getText().toString(), mPassword.getText().toString(),
        new Callback<Response>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Response result, Response response) {
                for(Header header : response.getHeaders()) {
                    Timber.d(header.getName() + ": " + header.getValue());
                }
            }
        });
```

I get the request headers for `"login.example.com/cas/login"` instead of the response headers received after submitting the form. How do I go about submitting the form and getting the response headers?

Comment: Why do you have 2 responses in your callback

Comment: @meda Good question, I could not figure out how to get the response back asynchronously without adding `Callback<Response>`, and the `success` method automatically gives back the response as well. So both `result` and `response` are the same. Hopefully I can find a better way to do this, but one step at a time.

Comment: OK just wondering because it looks strange, also the version your are using  is old. For header it will be better to log them inside of a custom interceptor

Comment: @meda I did see a few posts about `Interceptor` and/or `ResponseInterceptor`, but I was more familiar with using `Callback`. I figured I could try it this way, figure it out, then switch over. But now I'm not getting the results I expected, maybe I should try to use an `Interceptor` and see how that goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@GET` must be used instead of `@POST` to actually fill out the form and receive the response. All of the forms values must be submitted as a query as well. During the process, I switched to Retrofit 2, but I will post the equivalent Retrofit code as well.

Because of the way this specific form was set up, I also had to call the form once to parse the values of certain items (the login ticket, execution, and event), and a second time inputting those values plus the username and password. This would give me the correct response, and enable me to set the correct cookies.

Retrofit 2:

```
@GET("cas/login")
Observable<ResponseBody> login(@Query("lt") String loginTicket,
                            @Query("execution") String execution,
                            @Query("event") String event,
                            @Query("username") String username,
                            @Query("password") String password,
                            @Query("submit") String submit);
```

Retrofit 1:

```
@GET("/cas/login")
void login(@Query("lt") String loginTicket,
            @Query("execution") String execution,
            @Query("event") String event,
            @Query("username") String username,
            @Query("password") String password,
            @Query("submit") String submit,
            ResponseBody response);
```